# Why does GenerateFunctions fail looking for System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0 and throws a FileNotFoundException)?

Tags: c#, azure, msbuild, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function v2 is created as an DotNet Core library (2.1), using the latest 1.0.26 `Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Functions` NuGet package.

I am unable to build the Azure Functions because the `GenerateFunctions` task is looking for version 4.2.1.0 of `System.Runtime`. However there is no NuGet package of that particular version.

**Question**

Who is looking for System.Runtime 4.2.1.0 and how can I fix it?

Here is the diagnostic log section of the build that fails:

```
2>Target "_GenerateFunctionsPostBuild" in file "C:\Users\Chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets":
2>  Using "Move" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
2>  Task "Move"
2>    Task Parameter:SourceFiles=C:\NoSuchCompany\Service\src\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\NoSuchCompany.Demo.Service.AzureFunctions.pdb
2>    Task Parameter:DestinationFiles=C:\NoSuchCompany\Service\src\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\bin\NoSuchCompany.Demo.Service.AzureFunctions.pdb
2>    Task Parameter:OverwriteReadOnlyFiles=True
2>    Moving file from "C:\NoSuchCompany\Service\src\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\NoSuchCompany.Demo.Service.AzureFunctions.pdb" to "C:\NoSuchCompany\Service\src\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\bin\NoSuchCompany.Demo.Service.AzureFunctions.pdb".
2>  Done executing task "Move".
2>  Using "GenerateFunctions" task from assembly "C:\Users\Chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\build\netstandard1.0\..\..\tools\net46\\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.MSBuild.dll".
2>  Task "GenerateFunctions"
2>    Task Parameter:TargetPath=C:\NoSuchCompany\Service\src\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\bin\NoSuchCompany.Demo.Service.AzureFunctions.dll
2>    Task Parameter:OutputPath=C:\NoSuchCompany\Service\src\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\
2>    Function generator path: 'C:\Users\Chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\tools\net46\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator.exe'
2>    "C:\NoSuchCompany\Service\src\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\bin\NoSuchCompany.Demo.Service.AzureFunctions.dll " "C:\NoSuchCompany\Service\src\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\ "
2>    C:\Users\Chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error : System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
2>    C:\Users\Chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error : File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
2>    C:\Users\Chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error :    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)
2>    C:\Users\Chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error :    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
2>    C:\Users\Chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error :    at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryGenerateFunctionJsons()
2>    C:\Users\Chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error :    at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryRun()
2>    C:\Users\Chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error : 
2>    C:\Users\Chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error : WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
2>    C:\Users\Chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error : To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
2>    C:\Users\Chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error : Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
2>    C:\Users\Chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error : To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
2>    C:\Users\Chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error : 
2>    C:\Users\Chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error : Error generating functions metadata
2>    C:\Users\Chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error :
2>    C:\Users\Chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error : Metadata generation failed.
2>  Done executing task "GenerateFunctions" -- FAILED.
2>Done building target "_GenerateFunctionsPostBuild" in project "Demo.Service.AzureFunctions.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

**Update 1**

If I run the following command, I do get the exact same error:

> C:\Users\Chris.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\tools\net46>Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator.exe
>   "C:\NoSuchCompany\Service\src\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\bin\NoSuchCompany.Demo.Service.AzureFunctions.dll
>   " "C:\NoSuchCompany\Service\src\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\ "

I get the following output:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryGenerateFunctionJsons()
   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryRun()

Error generating functions metadata
```

**Update 2**

I wondered why the build uses the net framework version of `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator` since there is a `netcore` version. Out of curiosity, I tried it with the netcore version:

> C:\Users\Chris.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\tools\netcoreapp2.1>dotnet
>   Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator.dll
>   "C:\NoSuchCompany\Service\src\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\bin\NoSuchCompany.Demo.Service.AzureFunctions.dll"
>   "C:\NoSuchCompany\Service\src\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1"

No errors. I guess there is something wrong with the .net 4.6 version. u tho?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have located the condition to use the .Net Core runtime instead of the .Net Framework in the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets` file:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
      <UseNETCoreGenerator Condition="$(UseNETCoreGenerator)=='' AND ($(AzureFunctionsVersion) == 'v2' OR $(AzureFunctionsVersion) == 'v2-prerelease' )">true</UseNETCoreGenerator>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I then looked into my `.csproj` file of my Azure Functions and found out that the `AzureFunctionsVersion` tag was mispelled and was missing an `s` after Function:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  <AssemblyName>NoSuchCompany.Demo.Service.AzureFunctions</AssemblyName>
  <RootNamespace>NoSuchCompany.Demo.Service</RootNamespace>
  <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Once it got corrected, I got the expected successful build output, especially the part indicating the use of the .Net core generator:

```
Target "_GenerateFunctionsPostBuild" in file "C:\Users\Chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets":

2>  Set Property: UseNETCoreGenerator=true

2>  Using "Move" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
2>  Task "Move"
2>    Task Parameter:SourceFiles=C:\NoSuchCompany\Service\src\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\NoSuchCompany.Demo.Service.AzureFunctions.pdb
2>    Task Parameter:DestinationFiles=C:\NoSuchCompany\Service\src\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\bin\NoSuchCompany.Demo.Service.AzureFunctions.pdb
2>    Task Parameter:OverwriteReadOnlyFiles=True
2>    Moving file from "C:\NoSuchCompany\Service\src\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\NoSuchCompany.Demo.Service.AzureFunctions.pdb" to "C:\NoSuchCompany\Service\src\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\bin\NoSuchCompany.Demo.Service.AzureFunctions.pdb".
2>  Done executing task "Move".
2>  Using "GenerateFunctions" task from assembly "C:\Users\Chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\build\netstandard1.0\..\..\tools\net46\\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.MSBuild.dll".
2>  Task "GenerateFunctions"
2>    Task Parameter:TargetPath=C:\NoSuchCompany\Service\src\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\bin\NoSuchCompany.Demo.Service.AzureFunctions.dll
2>    Task Parameter:OutputPath=C:\NoSuchCompany\Service\src\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\
2>    Task Parameter:UseNETCoreGenerator=True
2>    Function generator path: 'dotnet'
2>    Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator.dll "C:\NoSuchCompany\Service\src\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\bin\NoSuchCompany.Demo.Service.AzureFunctions.dll " "C:\NoSuchCompany\Service\src\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\ "
2>  Done executing task "GenerateFunctions".
2>Done building target "_GenerateFunctionsPostBuild" in project "Demo.Service.AzureFunctions.csproj".
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing us in the right direction. Our case was slightly different in that the AzureFunctionsVersion element was empty:

`<AzureFunctionsVersion></AzureFunctionsVersion>`

We just had to update it as follows:

`<AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>`

Comment: Thanks for posting. I was running out with same issue, It worked like magic for me  ;)

Comment: I had changed host.json to `version` key to `2.0` and target framework to .NET Core 2.2 but the value in AzureFunctionsVersion xml tag was `v3`.