# Azure Function: MSB4018: The "GenerateFunctions" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, msbuild, azure-functions

I am getting the following error when I rebuild my Azure Function solution

```
error MSB4018: The "GenerateFunctions" task failed unexpectedly.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Tasks.GenerateFunctions.Execute() in /_/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.MSBuild/Tasks/GenerateFunctions.cs:line 46
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.3.3

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.0" />
```

Tried clearing the nuget cache, deleting the packages from %userprofile%.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\

When this initially started, I was able to fix resolve the issue by re-installing VS.
But the same error started to show up. This time even the reinstall is not fixing the issue.

Please help

Comment: could you please try adding this code in the property group of `.csproj` - `<UseNETCoreGenerator>true</UseNETCoreGenerator>`

Comment: @HariKrishna I tried that. Did not help

Comment: Have you clean and rebuild the solution and checked?

Comment: @HariKrishna I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally this error comes due to the following reasons like:

- dotnet installed path is not included in the Environment Variables path.
- Update the VS 2022 to the latest version 17.3.5

[image]

- Instead of re-installing the VS IDE, try creating the new function app with the same code and test.
- There were many similar issues reported in the VS 2017, VS 2019 IDES and fixed with the version updates. Identified the unique [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55081494) i.e., given by @Kzryzstof where he found one of the root causes of that similar error.

If that doesn't solve the issue, please raise the ticket in Official Page of [Azure-Functions GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/580) and to `AzCommunity[at]Microsoft[dot]com`.

Comment: dotnet path was missing in the environment variables. it worked after I updated that. Appreciate your help on this!!